# Auto populate the lookup

Tags: urlhacking

I have a query. Account is lookup to Contract which is look up to License key. both coctract and license key are custom objects. so wen from related list of contract object i create new license key then it must auto populate the account name on license key in reference to contracts(Account name.) how can dis be done

Comment: This can be done using a Trigger: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm. Please post what you have tried yourself first.

Comment: i want to do it with custom button

Comment: i tried doin it with custom button but no success. triggers work only for dml operations. i cud have done it with workflows bt WF dun support Lookup fields

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your object relations correctly.. I think you can create a Formula field on License with value _Contract__c.Account.Name_

Comment: yep i cud have done that but i want Account name on license key__c to be lookup and must get auto updated as per Contracts__c (Account Name)

Comment: can u post ur current URL you have tried and then we can suggest what to add/change to get it working

Comment: a0R/e?CF00NR0000001KQ7v=0002&CF00NR0000001KQ7v_lkid=a0cR0000002WUHf&retURL=%2Fa0cR0000002WUHf&CF00NR0000001KP3E_lkid={!Contracts__c.Id}

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of a url used in a custom button to autocreate an opportunity:-

```
/006/e?opp4_lkid={!Supplier.Id}&opp4={!HTMLENCODE(Supplier.Name)}
```

which auto populates the lookup field and sets to Supplier.Id and Supplier.Name.

What you would need to do is replace the /006/ part with the code for your sobject (get this from your current edit/new sfdc standard page). The tricky part is finding the {fieldId} and {fieldId_lkid} values to set to - try right-clicking on the lookup field in your browser and 'inspect element' from the html source code.

Have a look [here](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html) for a helpful post.

Comment: i had already visited that link. no success though

Comment: Perhaps you need: a0R/e?CF00NR0000001KQ7v=0002&CF00NR0000001KQ7v_lkid=a0cR0000002WUHf&CF00NR0000001KP3E_lkid={!Contracts__c.Id}&CF00NR0000001KP3E={!HTMLENCODE(Contracts__c.Name)} ?

Comment: Thanx the above method did help.. not completely though. I got idea. now thw other trouble that am facing is as soon as i remove https://cs2.salesforce.com from the url link. i cant save my url formula